# Fragment in layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'am trying to communicate betwen two fragment extended classes with the help of MainActivity bt always get an error{03-01 14:30:42.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1724): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfrag/com.example.myfrag.Tool}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment}

```
package com.example.myfrag;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;


public class ToolBoxFrag extends FragmentActivity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

     private static int seekvalue = 10;
      private static EditText edittext;

      ToolbarListener activityCallback;

      public interface ToolbarListener {
            public void onButtonClick(int position, String text);
      }

      public void onAttach(Fragment activity) {
            super.onAttachFragment(activity);
            try {
                activityCallback = (ToolbarListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement ToolbarListener");
            }
        }

      @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
           seekvalue = progress;
        }

       @Override
       public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }

       @Override
       public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final SeekBar seekbar = 
            (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        final Button button = 
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClicked(v);
            }
        });

        return ;
   }

   public void buttonClicked (View view) {
       activityCallback.onButtonClick(seekvalue, 
                 edittext.getText().toString());
   }
    }
```

TextFragment.java

```
package com.example.myfrag;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextFragment  extends FragmentActivity {

    private static TextView textview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        return;
    }

    public void changeTextProperties(int fontsize, String text)
    {
        textview.setTextSize(fontsize);
        textview.setText(text);
    }  
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.myfrag;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Tool extends FragmentActivity implements ToolBoxFrag.ToolbarListener {
 //public  TextFragment tf;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frag2);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(int fontsize, String text) {

        TextFragment tf = new TextFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main);
    tf.changeTextProperties(fontsize, text);
            }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, 
               menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentExampleActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentexample.ToolbarFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentexample.TextFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/main" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the class path you have described the fragment name path wrong .. 
it should be **com.example.myfrag** not **com.example.fragmentexample**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentExampleActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:name="com.example.myfrag.ToolbarFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:name="com.example.myfrag.TextFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/main" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i think you extend fragment not FragmentActivity.

Comment: I make a correction as per your suggestion,but still it is giving same error..,fragment in the xml is givng the error..,what shout i do to correct it.